# Misunderstanding in a Matplotlib program

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, colors

I was working on the code "Discrete distribution as horizontal bar chart", found here [LINK](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/horizontal_barchart_distribution.html), using Matplotlib 3.1.1

I've been circling around the question for a while, but I still can't figure it out: what's the meaning of the instruction: `category_colors = plt.get_cmap('RdYlGn')(np.linspace(0.15, 0.85, data.shape[1]))` ?

As `np.linspace(0.15, 0.85, data.shape[1])` resolves to `array([0.15 , 0.325, 0.5  , 0.675, 0.85 ])`, I first thought that the program was using the `colormap RdYlGn` (supposed to go from color=0.0 to color=1.0) and was then taking the 5 specific colors located at point 0.15, etc., 0.85

But, printing `category_colors` resolves to a `(5, 4) array`:

```
array([[0.89888504, 0.30549789, 0.20676663, 1.        ],
       [0.99315648, 0.73233372, 0.42237601, 1.        ],
       [0.99707805, 0.9987697 , 0.74502115, 1.        ],
       [0.70196078, 0.87297193, 0.44867359, 1.        ],
       [0.24805844, 0.66720492, 0.3502499 , 1.        ]])
```

I don't understand what these numbers refer to ???

Comment: Aren't those RGBA?

Comment: `[0.89888504, 0.30549789, 0.20676663, 1]` means an rgb-value (red=0.89..., green=0.30..., blue=0.20...., alpha=1, with 0 for no color and 1 for full color).  With `matplotlib.color.to_hex(...)` you could convert it to the hexadecimal format used on the web (`#e54e35`, a reddish color)

Comment: So, assuming rgb-values, how is it possible that `np.linspace(0.15, 0.85, 5)` (as `data.shape[1] is 5...)`, which resolves to `array([0.15 , 0.325, 0.5  , 0.675, 0.85 ])`, could lead to a `(5,4) array` with different rgb-values in each line? Probably something I don't understand in `plt.get_cmap` I guess: values 0.15, 0.325, 0.5, 0.675, 0.85 are fixed, aren't they? Nevertheless, rgb-values vary in each line... I am still confused with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plt.get_cmap('RdYlGn')` returns a function which maps a number between 0 and 1 to a corresponding color, where 0 gets mapped to red, 0.5 to yellow and 1 to green. Often, this function gets the name `cmap = plt.get_cmap('RdYlGn')`. Then `cmap(0)` (which is the same as `plt.get_cmap('RdYlGn')(0)`) would be the [rbga-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model) `(0.6470588235294118, 0.0, 0.14901960784313725, 1.0)` for `(red, green, blue, alpha`). In hexadecimal, this color would be `#a50026`.

By numpy's [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) magic, `cmap(np.array([0.15 , 0.325, 0.5  , 0.675, 0.85 ]))` gets the same result as `np.array([cmap(0.15), cmap(0.325), ..., cmap(0.85)])`. (In other words, many numpy functions applied to an array return an array of that function applied to the individual elements.)

So, the first row of `category_colors = cmap(np.linspace(0.15, 0.85, 5))` will be the rgba-values of the color corresponding to value `0.15`, or `0.89888504, 0.30549789, 0.20676663, 1.`. This is a color with 90% red, 31% green and 21% blue (and `alpha=1` for complete opaque), so quite reddish. The next row are the rgba values corresponding to `0.325`, and so on.

Here is some code to illustrate the concepts:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import to_hex  # convert a color to hexadecimal format
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable  # needed to create a custom colorbar
import numpy as np

cmap = plt.get_cmap('RdYlGn')
color_values = np.linspace(0.15, 0.85, 5)
category_colors = cmap(color_values)
plt.barh(color_values, 1, height=0.15, color=category_colors)
plt.yticks(color_values)
plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap), ticks=color_values)
plt.ylim(0, 1)
plt.xlim(0, 1.1)
plt.xticks([])
for val, color in zip(color_values, category_colors):
    r, g, b, a = color
    plt.text(0.1, val, f'r:{r:0.2f} g:{g:0.2f} b:{b:0.2f} a:{a:0.1f}\nhex:{to_hex(color)}', va='center')
plt.show()
```

[image: relation between colors and colormap]

PS: You might also want to read about [`norm`s](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html), which map an arbitrary range to the range 0,1 to be used by colormaps.

Comment: Very clear! I appreciated you put some code for a more complete understanding.

Comment: How can I apply RdYlGn to an image? For example, img = cv2.applyColorMap(img, RdYlGn)

Comment: @fisakhan See [Apply MatplotLib or custom colormap to OpenCV image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52498777/apply-matplotlib-or-custom-colormap-to-opencv-image)