# matplotlib imshow gray colormap additional preprocess

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I have bunch of images, randomly I figured out that best preprocessing for my images is using matplotlib imshow with cmap=gray. This is my RGB image (I can't publish the original images, this is a sample that I created to make my point. So the original images are not noiseless and perfect like this):

[image: Raw Image]

When I  use `plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')` the image will be:
[image]

I wanted to implement this process in Opencv. I tried to use OpenCV colormaps but there wasn't any gray one there. I used [these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52498777/apply-matplotlib-or-custom-colormap-to-opencv-image) but the result is like the first image not the second one. ([result here](https://github.com/HSILA/Notebooks/blob/main/colormap.ipynb))

So I was wondering besides changing colormaps, what preprocessing does matplotlib apply on images when we call `imshow`?

P.S: You might suggest binarization, I've tested both techniques but on my data binarization will ruin some of the samples which this method (matplotlib) won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`cv::normalize`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga87eef7ee3970f86906d69a92cbf064bd) with `NORM_MINMAX` should help you. it can map intensity values so the darkest becomes black and the lightest becomes white, regardless of what the absolute values were.

this section of OpenCV docs contains example code. it's a permalink.

> or so that minIdst(I)=alpha, maxIdst(I)=beta when normType=NORM_MINMAX (for dense arrays only)

that means, for NORM_MINMAX, alpha=0, beta=255. these two params have different meanings for different normTypes. for NORM_MINMAX it seems that the code automatically swaps them so the lower value of either is used as the lower bound etc.

further, the range for `uint8` type data is `0 .. 255`. giving `1` only makes sense for float data.

example:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
im = cv.imread("m78xj.jpg")
normalized = cv.normalize(im, dst=None, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv.NORM_MINMAX)
cv.imshow("normalized", normalized)
cv.waitKey(-1)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: output]

apply a median blur to remove noisy pixels (which go beyond the average gray of the text):

```py
blurred = cv.medianBlur(im, ksize=5)
# ...normalize...
```

[image: median blur and then normalize]

or do the scaling manually. apply the median blur, find the maximum value in *that* version, then apply it to the *original* image.

```py
output = im.astype(np.uint16) * 255 / blurred.max()
output = np.clip(output, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
# ...
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I tried this approach but whatever alpha and beta I use (0,1 - 0,255 - 0,127) the output is a completely black image [as you can see here](https://imgur.com/eNazV0O). `img = cv2.normalize(img, 0, 1, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)`

Comment: okay now I've tried this given your picture (see file name, matches picture in your post) and I get a decent result. the text is not *perfectly* white because the file contains sharpening, which causes some noisy pixels to be 255 instead.